# error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, matrices

Los elementos puntos de silla cumplen una de estas
condiciones :

1. Dentro de la fila son mínimos y dentro de la columna son máximos.
2. Dentro de la fila son máximos y dentro de la columna son mínimos

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define N 10

typedef struct
{
    int fils, cols;  
    unsigned int mat[N][N];
}tmatriz;   


int main()
{
    tmatriz m1={4,3,{{4,4,1},{4,3,0},{3,5,0}, {4,2,0}}};

    int i, j;
    int maxFils [m1.fils] = {-999, -999, -999, -999};
    int minCols [m1.cols] = {999, 999, 999};    
    printf("Datos de la matriz m1:\n");
    for (i=0; i<m1.fils; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<m1.cols; j++)
            printf("%3u ", m1.mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0; i<m1.fils; i++){
        for (j=0; j<m1.cols; j++){
            if (m1.mat [i] [j] > maxFils [i]){
                maxFils [i] = m1.mat [i] [j];
            }
            if (m1.mat [i] [j] < minCols [j]){
                minCols [j] = m1.mat [i] [j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<m1.fils; i++){
        for (j=0; j<m1.cols; j++){
            if (maxFils [i] == minCols [j]){
                printf ("Punto de silla en (%d, %d) y su valor es %d\n", i, j, m1.mat [i] [j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No entiendo por qué no me funciona este algoritmo

Comment: ¿Qué es un punto de silla? ¿Cómo sabré que me he encontrado un punto de silla si tengo uno delante? La primera estructura que defines no tiene llave de cierre ni nombre. Y la indentación del código cuesta de entender. A `main` le falta el retorno.

Comment: ya está aclarado

Comment: a que te referis con no funciona? no encuentra esos puntos que buscas?? que puntos te tira en tu ejemplo?

Comment: Básicamente al  intentar compilar me salta un error diciendo:  error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
     int maxFils [m1.fils] = {-999, -999, -999, -999};
     ^

Comment: @JordiGarcía claro, estás usando un arreglo de longitud variable, y eso no está permitido.

Comment: ¿qué significa que esté haciendo un arreglo de longitud variable? es la primera vez que me pasa y no entiendo dónde lo estoy haciendo

Comment: @JordiGarcía Siguiendo [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/19610), he editado el título para ajustarlo al problema real y facilitar las búsquedas de futuros usuarios con problemas similares. Espero que no te moleste.

Comment: No me parece mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que estas en C99, o que usas un compilador con soporte de *arreglos* de longitud variable. El compilador te lo dice muy claro:

> `variable-sized object may not be initialized`

Estas usando un *arreglo* de **longitud variable**: el tamaño de dicho *arreglo* **no es conocido en tiempo de compilación**, sino en *tiempo de ejecución*.

En el momento de generar el código para inicializar dicho *arreglo* `maxFils`, el compilador **no sabe cuál es su tamaño**. Entonces, **no sabe cuantos datos esperar, ni cuantos *bytes* copiar**. El compilador **no** sabe como inicializarlo, precisamente, porque desconoce su tamaño.

Tienes **2** opciones:

#### Usa *arreglos* de longitud fija:

```
int maxFils[N] = { -999, -999, ... };
```

#### Inicializa de forma directa los elementos del arreglo:

```
int maxFils[m1.fils];
int idx;

for( idx = 0; idx < m1.fils; ++idx )
  maxFils[idx] = -999;
```

La 1ª opción es la mas *portable* entre compiladores.

Comment: yo diría que ambas opciones son igual de portables, no? Salvo obviamente que trabajes con compiladores que no soporten C99... que ya les vale si los siguen usando jejeje

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. En C99, los VLA son *obligatorios*, mientras que en C11 son *opcionales* (se establece la macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__` si **no** lo soportan). Ese código puede compilar perfecto en C99, y *fallar* en C11 bajo ciertos compiladores.

Comment: Interesante, se nota que no estoy al día en lo que se refiere a C

Comment: Ciertamente, será difícil encontrar 1 compilador que **no** lo soporte ;-)